# Errors in running docker images

Tags: r, containers, bioinformatics, bioconductor, docker-image

I'm fairly new to using dockers and my application is in bioinformatics. I pulled a docker image called bioconductor/release_base and have been having issues in running this image.

I get the following error:

```
rserver[133]: ERROR system error 98 (Address already in use); OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::http::initTcpIpAcceptor(rstudio::core::http::SocketAcceptorService<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, const string&, const string&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/TcpIpSocketUtils.hpp:103; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerMain.cpp:438
rserver[136]: ERROR system error 98 (Address already in use); OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::http::initTcpIpAcceptor(rstudio::core::http::SocketAcceptorService<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, const string&, const string&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/TcpIpSocketUtils.hpp:103; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerMain.cpp:438--
```

And this happens with any images I'm trying to run. Would there be a possible solution for this?

Thanks,

RN

Comment: Can you post the command you entered that caused this error? I can't reproduce this, however, I also am not getting RStudio Server to run, either with bioconductor/release_base or its parent, rocker/rstudio. You may want to try rocker/rstudio, and if that doesn't work, contact its maintainers.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for responding. I was trying the command docker run -it bioconductor/release_base .. I'm guessing there is an issue in the parent image may be?

Comment: Yes, rocker/rstudio is the parent image, and it seems there's a problem getting RStudio to run in that container. Its maintainer is listed here: https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/~/dockerfile/

Comment: Hi Dan, I have another weird issue. I'm on linux and OSx to install and run docker, on linux it runs fine,  however on Mac OS, although am able to run images and install packages in R, the VM would always show me a timeout status instead of running. And this is a issue I've always had. I'm not sure if this is a bug or what in docker installation related to IP addresses on VM not talking to the docker machine but still running the tasks. Have you seen similar issues?

Comment: NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
biotroll            virtualbox   Timeout                           
default    -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown